# Autofac Invalid Configuration Prevention/Detection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

Is there a nice and quick way with AutoFac to detect dependency resolution exceptions without having to resolve the whole dependency hierarchy, or resolve the hierarchy quickly and detect the issues?

I know about the `AttachToComponentRegistration` method and have hooked into the preparing method, so I can see exactly whats trying to be activated when it fails resolution. However this slows down the resolution process because I'm logging every call.

The problem I'm trying to solve specifically is when someone accidentally adds something like a string to a constructor, in this case AutoFac will fail, but won't tell you the class which its failing to resolve.

Example message:

> Cannot choose between multiple constructors with equal length 1 on
>   type 'System.String'

Comment: Would be difficult to have such a feature. Service having a `String` parameter in constructor will be resolve by having a `Func<String, IService>` dependency.

Comment: With xUnit and [Fluent autofac assertions](https://awesome-incremented.blogspot.ru/2016/01/fluently-testing-your-autofac.html) you can test your dependency resolution easily. Autofac modules help here as well to isolate/group dependency tree and test them accordingly.

Comment: @AntonKrouglov That looks good for testing individual dependencies, but may not work as well in the case of large dependency trees being constructed from autofac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like a really nice solution is currently possible for this, however I've come up with a half way house which basically stores all resolution requests in a static list that you can add to in `AttachToComponentRegistration` and access when an error gets thrown during dependency resolution.

```
    public static class AutoFacRequestLog
{
    private static object syncer = new object();
    private static List<Type> RequestedTypes { get; set; } = new List<Type>();

    public static void AddRequest(Type type)
    {
        lock (syncer)
            RequestedTypes.Add(type);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetMostRecent(int i)
    {
        lock (syncer)
            return RequestedTypes.Skip(Math.Max(0, RequestedTypes.Count - i)).Take(i);
    }
}
```